# Writing a USB Driver for a canon eos t2i

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, driver

Canon already has an application that allows me to stream the live view to my computer.  I don't like the application because it crashes a lot when open for long periods of time, and to use it as a webcam you have to cobble together another application to watch a certain section of the screen and it gets complicated.

I'm wondering if there is a way to "easily" stream video from a USB device connected to my computer with objective-c and cocoa.

I'm also thinking that Canon might have their drivers closed source, so people can't copy them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Canon provides a [SDK for Windows and Mac](http://usa.canon.com/cusa/support/consumer/eos_slr_camera_systems/eos_digital_slr_cameras/eos_rebel_t2i_ef_s_18_55mm_is_kit#DriversAndSoftware).  Presumably you can use this to write your own software if you're unhappy with what their app provides.